# Include C++ library in Netbeans 7.0

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm trying the use [this library (RollPlay)](http://www.divnull.com/rollplay/) in my project but I don't know how to include it in my C++ project in Netbeans. Would I just add the .dll and .h files into the project folder, add the files to the project? I'm new to Netbeans and using non built-in libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A library would normally reside in its own installation directory so you would need to point NB to where that is. 
If you right-click the project name in the "Projects"  window, you'll have a Properties option.

- Select the Build/C++ compiler option to add the directory for the .h files.
- Select the Build/Linker to add the directory for the dll file.

Comment: Which if I copy those files into my project folder would be the project folder's directory of course?

Comment: @Portal If you copy the headers to a folder in your project, the compile will will most likely work. Use `#include"folder/header.h"` syntax. How the dll-files, the files with the actual code will fare, I do not know.

Comment: What about the .lib file included? My friend added it in the project properties in Visual Studio. Do I have to do something similar or is the .dll enough?

Comment: @Portal The lib file only needs to be included like I described, I'm quite certain.

Comment: Yes.I would suppose. Now a dll is a library loaded at runtime if my understanding is correct. You might actually need code to load it.

Comment: What do you do once you get to the "Build/C++" for importing `.h` files?

Comment: @EthanLeyden An .h file is just a file. You tell your compiler to look for it in the proper directory. The Build/C++ step is completely unrelated to finding .h files.

Comment: How do you add the directory? I see a list of options, which got me confused.

Comment: Project options, c++, you will find include file or directories in the compiler options.  Ask a new question if you cant find the answer to your troubles here. This discussion is unrelated to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans 8.2, to include a header file (.h) folder in your IDE, you would do something like this:

1. On the top menu bar, Select Tools -> Options
2. Select C/C++ -> Code Assistance tab, Select C++ Compiler Tab, then click 'Add' (Image below shows highlighted folder added after clicking add)

[image]

But this will not be enough, code will not compile. Because some how this option will only remove the error in IDE.

To remove the error during compilation you need to pass the include folder as parameter to MinGw toolset.

1. Right click your C++ project and select 'Properties' from the context menu
2. Select 'General' from the tree on the left, then 'Add' the same folder which you added in the previous steps.
   [image]

Now on running you should see the folder added as argument in the following command:

```
g++    -c -g -I../../../../../dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include -MMD .....
```

I am using MinGw from: [nuwen](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) and adding header files from [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg). But any MinGw you are using it should not matter, also you can include any libraries/header files' folder this way.