# netbeans mysql connector No such file or directory (MinGW)

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, mysql-connector

i try to link mysql-connector 1.1.3 in Netbeans (7.3, Windows 7) with Mingw-Compiler to my c++ Project. 
In the project properties i have add all mysql-connector directories (include, lib, cppcon) under "included Directorys" and under Linker "Additionell Linker Directorys". I added the boost libs to.
But in the Compiler Output say always:

**fatal error: mysql_connection.h: No such file or directory**

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for help...

the complete output:

> "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
>   make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Toni/Desktop/dev/Wiesel/new/tests/sql_test2'
>   "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/sql_test2.exe
>   make[2]: Entering directory`/cygdrive/c/Users/Toni/Desktop/dev/Wiesel/new/tests/sql_test2'
>   mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
>   rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
>   g++    -c -g -I/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32 -I/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32/include -I/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32/include/cppconn -I/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32/lib -I/D/libs/boost_1_53_0 -I/D/libs/boost_1_53_0/boost -I/D/libs/boost_1_53_0/libs -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
>   main.cpp:9:30: fatal error: mysql_connection.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target `build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o' failed
>   make[2]: [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1 (ignored)
>   mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
>   g++ -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/sql_test2 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/D/libs/boost_1_53_0/boost -L/D/libs/boost_1_53_0/libs -L/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32 -L/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32/include -L/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32/include/cppconn -L/D/libs/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32/lib -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlcppconn-static -lmysqlcppconn -static
>   g++.exe: error: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: No such file or directory
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target`dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/sql_test2.exe' failed
>   make[2]: [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/sql_test2.exe] Error 1 (ignored)
>   make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Toni/Desktop/dev/Wiesel/new/tests/sql_test2'
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/cygdrive/c/Users/Toni/Desktop/dev/Wiesel/new/tests/sql_test2'

Comment: Code please? We can't help without it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

A library would normally reside in its own installation directory so you would need to point NB to where that is. If you right-click the project name in the "Projects" window, you'll have a Properties option.

1. Select the Build/C++ compiler option to add the directory for the .h files.
2. Select the Build/Linker to add the directory for the dll file.

[Include C++ library in Netbeans 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799493/include-c-library-in-netbeans-7-0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what i do. I add the header files directory under "Build/C++ compiler/include Directorys" and under "Build/Linker/Additional Library Directorys" the lib Directory

Comment: Are you adding the header to your project?

Comment: You'll also need to reference the mysql lib in something like C:\Program Files\MySQL\

Comment: yes, the mysql_connection.h, mysql_driver.h files are under "D:\libs\mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.3-win32\include" and this directory i have include under "Project Properties/Build/C++ compiler/include Directorys" and for save under "Build/Linker/Additional Library Directorys" to. this is very mysterious

Comment: adn under libraries i added the single lib files (mysqlcppconn.lib, mysqlcppconn-static.lib, mysqlcppconn.dll)

Comment: Hmmm. In your g++ build config, add -m32 as an argument.

Comment: I had a similar issue with my setup of the mysql++ driver. This is an Eclipse screenshot of my eclipse setup. This might help with your Netbeans setup: http://i.imgur.com/nlqURc1.png Note that this is on a unix machine though, so directories will differ.

Comment: thanks for your help, on unix i had never problems with linking my libraries, think this is a problem with the netbeans --> mingw-compiler interaction... All the directorys included correctly